# Why does the Community bot create duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

I am just wondering why the community bot creates a tag that already exists. For example, we already have the tag [java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream) that is largely used now (already 432 questions on 2,520 questions concerning the new Java stream API).

But I saw this today, which is the tag [java.util.stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.stream):

[image]

This tag has only one question tagged, but in the future we may have a request to merge the tags has they have the same purpose.

So I'm just wondering why the bot creates tags; is it really necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community didn't create that tag, [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) did. Community just owns the initial (blank) revision of the tag wiki, as you (the user) don't create the wiki when you create the tag (by using it on a question).

The tag wiki has to exist though, so a blank revision is created with Community as the user.

Comment: Interestingly, other older tags don't seem to follow this pattern. I can't explain that :( Some others do though

Comment: And how to know who is the creator of a tag?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer: correlation. Take the time of the tag wiki creation by Community, then look for edits adding that tag at the exact same time.