# How do you know who created a tag?

Tags: support, tags

If you read this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287414/3653989) you will see in the image that the user Community appears as creator of the `java.util.stream` tag. But in the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287415/3653989) of the question BradleyDotNET says that the user [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) created this tag.

But how I can see this?

I created the tag [drupal-migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-migrate) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23908439/3653989) but I don't know where find my name as the creator, if you go to the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29014528/revisions), you see the Community again.

Comment: Not a dupe, but might give you some insight into what's going on and where to see the name of a creator (if it's shown at all): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287783/what-tags-are-created-by-nobody

Comment: Don't confuse the name on the first revision of the tag **wiki** with whomever created the tag. You can create a tag but not the associated wiki.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And really when I create a tag?

Comment: When you create the tag, *only a blank tag wiki is created*. Only when you first edit the tag wiki is a name attached to that.

Comment: @Kendra in this case there is not name http://stackoverflow.com/tags/drupal-migrate/info

Comment: off topic, but I'm not seeing any reason for this tag to exist.  "migration" and "drupal" seem sufficient on their own.  We don't also need separate tags for every pairing of every tag.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer That's correct. If you read the answer by Animuson on the linked question, that would be because you did not earn the Taxonimist badge from this tag. As it appears you do not have the badge yet, you can still earn it from this badge. If you _do_ earn the badge from this tag, then your name will appear on the page

Comment: Any reason you need to know who created a tag? Tags are either acceptable/useful or not; Either Sym or not; etc.

Comment: just be informed